# Change the structure of a website from wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am trying to setup a webpage using wordpress. The initial design of my website contains several elements. I have for exaple the following image:

[image]

In the top I have my website header image and then I have the home page. What I am trying to figure out is how can I change the position of those two elements from the template I am using. I need the home page not to overlapping at all with the header image. How can I control things like that from the wordpress?

Comment: You need to post code to get any sort of a solution however i think in your css you can specify `z-index` which will show them in priority. set navbars z-index higher than the z-index of home page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and add some custom CSS from the `Appearance` Tab. To see what your wordpress template calls different divisions, open your webpage in chrome and press F12. After pressing the function button you can click the box and pointer in the top left which will allow you to select different divisions.

```
#header{text-align:center;}
```

Above is an example of how you would code in the custom css. Make sure to code outside of the commented lines that are placed by default.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Don't just edit the theme CSS - every time the theme is updated this will be overridden. Create a child theme and put overrides there, so they will be preserved.